# Duplicate Entry for Video Embed Field which not allow to save node

Tags: 7, files, nodes

> **Content Type** : VideoDisplay
>
> **Fields** : Name of Video(Type: String), Video(Type: Video Embed Field), Artist(Type : Node Reference Field)

User already created a record of type `VideoDisplay`. Now as per requirement I can add more

> Artist to Existing Video.

So I take this approach:-

```
$node_vids = node_load($videoId);
$node_vids->field_artist[LANGUAGE_NONE] = array(
               0 => array('nid' => $form_state['values']['nid']));
$node = node_submit($node_vids);
node_save($node);
```

But it gives me error saying:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'node-143-0-0-und' for key 'PRIMARY'

This error comes up while inserting data in Video(`Type:Video Embed Field`). But here I want to save Artist(`Type : Node Reference Field`) field only. I get to know that `node_save` actually saves all the attributes of Content Type.

After searching net I try to use **field_attach_update()** but again it is throwing 
same exception. Please let me know any solution to  get out of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

field_sql_storage_field_storage_write() function exposed by Drupal helps to update desired single field only. Calling this will not invoke any hooks.